# Питон. Список чисел преобразовать в двумерный список

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Решаю задачу.

Вводится список целых чисел в строку через пробел. С помощью list comprehension сформировать из них двумерный список lst размером n x n (квадратную таблицу чисел).
То есть, на входе, например: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`
На выходе: `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`
Казалось что всё просто, но первое решение не прошло (думаю, нет смысла объяснять почему):

```
lst = list(map(int, input().split()))
n = int(len(lst) ** 0.5)
lst = [[lst[i] for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
print(lst)
```

Решил сделать для начала хоть как-то, даже с numpy, а потом уже перевести в list comprehension.

```
import numpy as np
lst = list(map(int, input().split()))
n = int(len(lst) ** 0.5)
lst_split = np.array_split(lst, n)
lst_new = lst_split.tolist()
print(lst)
```

Однако, не тут-то было. Numpy сделал нужную матрицу, но обратно выпускать ее из своих нампаевских объятий уже не захотел. Если оставить всё в виде array (то есть, отказаться от этой операции: `lst_new = lst_split.tolist()`), то получается такой ответ:

```
[array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6]), array([7, 8, 9])]
```

что не является правильным ответом. Но если сделать "как надо", т.е. с обратным преобразованием в список, то получаем такую ошибку:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tolist'
```

Первая мысль была: "Как же так? Неправда, братцы. Он, наверно, пошутил?" (с). Но немного придя в себя я понял, что (скорее всего) подразумевается тот list, который охватывается эти три  массива:

```
array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6]), array([7, 8, 9])
```

Тогда стала задача - как перевести в списки те массивы, которые у меня внутри списка? Была идея сделать это, так сказать, методом лапароскопии, то есть так:

```
for i in lst_split:
    i = i.tolist()
```

Но не сработало.
Тогда я решил что цифры, что поступают на вход программе, можно перевести в массив таким образом, чтобы массивы не были в списке. Но тут я запутался окончательно и понял, что зашел к глухие дебри.
Итак, вопрос:

1. как решить эту задачу с numpy и без него?
   Уже не спрашиваю про list comprehension, т.к. есть надежда что обычное решение я в него как-то втисну.
2. в чем ошибочна логика моего решения? Это по сути даже более важный вопрос, т.к. он уже про понимание. Такое ощущение, что я не понимаю чего-то важного и тонкого из списков, хотя и изучал эту тему по разным источникам.
   Спасибо всем, кто прочитал до конца и кто сможет ответить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать срезы и шаг в `range`. Шаг (он же размер стороны квадрата) вычисляется как кв. корень из длины списка.

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
side = int(len(lst) ** 0.5)
out = [lst[i:i + side] for i in range(0, len(lst), side)]
print(out)
```

Без срезов (вложенное списковое включение)

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
side = int(len(lst) ** 0.5)
out = [[lst[j] for j in range(i, i + side, 1)] for i in range(0, len(lst), side)]
print(out)
```

numpy

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
a = np.array(lst).reshape(int(len(lst)**0.5),-1).tolist()
print(a)
```

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Всё заработало!

Comment: Там где без срезов только исправил " for i in range(0, len(lst), side) " иначе не хотел брать последний список.